# Can't increment last element with previous element sibling in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm trying to complete a small task. When the user clicks on one of the boxes, it should increment that box by 2, and the box next to it by 1. If a box has another box on the left of it, it should increment that box by 1 as well as the one on the right. However, whilst the code works for all the boxes on the page, when clicking on the last box, the box prior to it does not increment. Below is the code.

```js
function boxInc(element){

var number = parseInt(element.innerHTML);
number+=2;
element.innerHTML = number;


rightNumber = parseInt(element.nextElementSibling.innerHTML);
rightNumber++;
element.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = rightNumber;

leftNumber = parseInt(element.previousElementSibling.innerHTML);
leftNumber++;
element.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = leftNumber;

}
```

```css
#container div {
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  background: rgb(10,200,40);
  float: left;
  margin: 1vw;
  padding: 1vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="1" onclick="boxInc(this)">0</div>
<div id="2" onClick="boxInc(this)">0</div>
<div id="3" onClick="boxInc(this)" >0</div>
<div id="4" onClick="boxInc(this)">0</div>
<div id="5" onClick="boxInc(this)">0</div>
<div id="6" onClick="boxInc(this)">0</div>
</div>
```

I'd like a vanilla JavaScript solution as opposed to a jQuery one.

Comment: This: `element.nextElementSibling.innerHTM` will throw (check the console) on the last element. That prevents the next few lines from executing. All you need to do is test for the existence of each element prior to attempting to write to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right way, as stated by **Randy Casburn** on the comments, you just need to check for the existance of the siblings before try to get or set content in them.

Also, I think that you can use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, because you are just setting text, not using HTML, so don't need to invoke HTML "compiler" for that.
Below code should help you, take a look:

```js
function boxInc(element){
  var number = parseInt(element.textContent);
  number += 2;
  element.textContent = number;

  if (element.nextElementSibling != null){
    rightNumber = parseInt(element.nextElementSibling.textContent);
    rightNumber++;
    element.nextElementSibling.textContent = rightNumber;
  }

  if (element.previousElementSibling != null){
    leftNumber = parseInt(element.previousElementSibling.textContent);
    leftNumber++;
    element.previousElementSibling.textContent = leftNumber;
  }

}
```

```css
#container div {
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  background: rgb(10,200,40);
  float: left;
  margin: 1vw;
  padding: 1vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="1" onclick="boxInc(this)">0</div>
  <div id="2" onClick="boxInc(this)">0</div>
  <div id="3" onClick="boxInc(this)">0</div>
  <div id="4" onClick="boxInc(this)">0</div>
  <div id="5" onClick="boxInc(this)">0</div>
  <div id="6" onClick="boxInc(this)">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for detailing my comment :-) - but there is no need to test for undefined. The property will be null if there is no element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling - so only need to check for null.

Comment: Ah okay, I thought that may have been the issue but I did not execute properly. Thank you very much.